# Need to clarify Django doc about maximum URL Conf

Tags: django, url

There is one section in the documentation of Django which I don't understand clearly:

> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       ...
>       ) 
>   urlpatterns += patterns('',
>       ...
>       )
>
> Python lists have unlimited size, so there's no limit to how many URL
>   patterns you can construct. The only limit is that you can only create
>   254 at a time (the 255th argument is the initial prefix argument).

The doc is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

My question is 
1) does it mean for each:

> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       ...
>       )

I have only 254 urls.

2) does it mean if I split up to 3 patterns like this:

> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       ...
>       ) 
>   urlpatterns += patterns('',
>       ...
>       )
>   urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       ...
>       )

I can declare 254 * 3 URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Correct and correct. You can only specify a maximum of 255 arguments in a Python function call.